# ValueError: could not convert string to float: −0,5063291139

Tags: python, csv

This is part of large csv file ( I show you only first column):

```
0
0
0
−0,5063291139
0,5063291139
0
0
0,6666666667
```

I am getting only data from first column. When I am trying to covert these to float:

```
with open("GOLD.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f ,delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        print float(row[0])
```

I get:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: −0,5063291139
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You have two values, `−0` and `5063291139`

Comment: The comma used as the decimal point is incompatible with comma as a field delimiter.  Change one of them and try again.

Comment: it appears to me the comma in GOLD.csv is a unicode character which is different than the comma you use in the code portion. I converted GOLD.csv to be only ASCII and your example runs fine.

Comment: How to convert GOLD.csv to be only ASCII?

Comment: where did the data come from?

Comment: Google Docs Excel file.

Comment: Are you sure `0.5063291139` is the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.` instead of `,` in the numbers. Change the line into

```
print float(str_replace(",",".",row[0]))
```

or what you like best to change the comma into a dot.

Comment: I made the changes. Now I get: ValueError: could not convert string to float: −0.5063291139

Comment: Is the "-" in that string an actual "-", or a unicode em-dash or something else screwy?  Yeah, that's not the "-" character, it just looks like it. You'll need to do another str_replace() on it.